# Getting Projected bounds information in pyproj

Tags: python, pyproj

I'm building an API where user can insert a number (3857, 27700,etc.) and my API will give the projected bounds.
I'm using pyproj's

```
crs_number = 27700    
crs_custom = CRS.from_user_input(crs_number)
crs_custom.area_of_use.bounds
```

this function is giving me bounds but it is showing bounds like

> -8.82,49.79,1.92,60.94

instead of

> -90619.29,10097.13,612435.55,1234954.16

How do I get the expected bounds?

Comment: The `area_of_use.bounds` are in WGS84 so that property is consistent across all CRSs, so just project them to your target if that's what you're looking for

Comment: How can I project?

Comment: There are examples in the docs:  https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#transformations-from-crs-to-crs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution following the @mikewatt advise

```
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

in_crs = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
out_crs = CRS.from_epsg(3857)
x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = out_crs.area_of_use.bounds
```

Then project your bottom left corner and top right corner in the output crs :

```
proj = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 3857, always_xy=True)
bl = proj.transform(x_min, y_min)
tr = proj.transform(x_max, y_max)
```

### Edit

Following this question I asked on github and thanks to @snowman you can use :

```py
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

crs = CRS("EPSG:3857")
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(crs.geodetic_crs, crs, always_xy=True)
transformer.transform_bounds(*crs.area_of_use.bounds)
```

you can find the [issue](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/809) and the [PR](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/pull/810) on github.