# How to check which geometries in a GeoDataFrame are within the bounds/limits of the projection/coordinate system?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

Is there a pre-built function that I can use to identify which of the geometries in a GeoDataFrame fall within the bounds of a CRS?

I'm asking because, currently, GeoPandas allows me to create points that are wildly outside of a CRS' bounds.

For example, [WGS84 (`EPSG:4326`)](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) has the following bounds:

- `x_min=-180`, `x_max=180`, `y_min=-90`, `y_max=90`

However, I can create `POINT (-500 900)` and GeoPandas won't throw any kind of error.

Similarly, the [Texas State Mapping System (`EPSG:3081`)](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3081/) has the following bounds:

- `x_min=334235.2323`, `x_max=1651722.6917`, `y_min=428079.3639`, `y_max=1608994.9702`

However, I can create `POINT (-50000000 70000000)` and GeoPandas won't throw any kind of error.

Here's a quick example (in code) of what I'm talking about.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

test_1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'my_id':[1,2,3]},
                          geometry=gpd.points_from_xy([-180,180,-500], 
                                                      [-90,90,900]),
                          crs='epsg:4326')


test_2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'my_id':[11,12,13]},
                          geometry=gpd.points_from_xy([334235.2323, 
                                                       1651722.6917, 
                                                       -50000000], 
                                                      [428079.3639, 
                                                       1608994.9702, 
                                                       70000000]),
                          crs='epsg:3081')
```

Notice how in GeoPandas allowed the creation of both GeoDataFrames without any hiccups.

So, my question is: is there an easy way to identify geometries that fall outside of a CRS' "legal" bounds?

## Edit

I've built on top of what [@Babak Fi Foo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/78412/babak-fi-foo) suggested and created the following function:

```py
import pyproj
def within_crs_bounds(gdf):
    ref_crs = pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(gdf.crs.to_epsg())
    
    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = ref_crs.area_of_use.bounds
    
    proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(4326, ref_crs.to_epsg(), always_xy=ref_crs.is_projected)
    
    crs_x_min, crs_y_min = proj.transform(x_min, y_min)
    crs_x_max, crs_y_max = proj.transform(x_max, y_max)
    
    gdf_bounds = gdf.geometry.bounds
    result = ((gdf_bounds['minx']>=crs_x_min)&
              (gdf_bounds['miny']>=crs_y_min)&
              (gdf_bounds['maxx']<=crs_x_max)&
              (gdf_bounds['maxy']<=crs_y_max))
    return result
```

For the `test_1` GeoDataFrame, this implementation works just fine. However, for the `test_2` GeoDataFrame, it does not work. The `crs_x_min`, `crs_y_min`, `crs_x_max` and `crs_y_max` variables get values far away from the true bounds (as seen on the [EPSG:3081 Spatial Reference Site](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3081/)). I expect them to hold  `(334235.2323, 428079.3639, 1651722.6917, 1608994.9702)`, but they actually hold `(331226.35401596106, 429093.9412772637, 1583305.6741846378, 1608302.6853412518)` instead.

## Note

Related GitHub issues and pull requests:

- [Issue: ENH: Method that checks which geometries in a GeoDataFrame are within the bounds/limits of the projection/coordinate system Issue #1915](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1915)
- [Issue: would it be possible to have the CRS bounds in its original unit ? Issue #809](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/809)
- [PR: ENH: Add Transformer.transform_bounds](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/pull/810)

Comment: I don't think there is. GeoPandas uses `pyproj` to represent the CRS of a GeoDataFrame. This thread might give some clue to define your own method: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390517/getting-projected-bounds-information-in-pyproj

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the bounds of the CRS. you can find it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390517/getting-projected-bounds-information-in-pyproj).

```
from pyproj import CRS
import geopandas as gpd

crs= CRS.from_epsg(4326)
x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = crs.area_of_use.bounds
```

Then you can get the bounds of each geometry.

```
gdf[['minx','miny','maxx','maxy']] = gdf.geometry.bounds
```

What remains is filtering them out:

```
    gdf = gdf[
             (gdf['minx']>x_min)&
             (gdf['miny']>y_min)&
             (gdf['maxx']<x_max)&
             (gdf['maxy']<y_max)&
             ]
```

This way all shapes that are within the bounds of CRS will remain in your geo data frame.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the tip!!! For some reason, though, it doesn't work properly with my second example (EPSG:3081).  I've added some notes to the bottom of my answer to explain the issues. Any idea of how to get around those limitations?

Comment: I tried to find an answer to EPSG:3081. I could not find a method where those coordinates are obtained automatically. Good that you opened an issue in Github!
I suggest you enter the bounds manually to solve your problem until a solution is implemented in Pyproj library.